# Only part of the response is retrieved at the ionic 4 front-end

Tags: node.js, angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, middleware

I am sending an http GET request from ionic to a NodeJS server using tokens. I get a message that data has been successfully retrieved. However, the data property of the response is not sent to the frontend and is assigned to undefined when i try to log it in the console. Here is the code for my ionic request:

```
 getPoints() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.getAuthorizationToken());
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    console.log(this.getAuthorizationToken());
   return this.http
      .get(environment.apiUrl + "/user/getCurrentPoints", {
        headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

This is the code inside an ionic component where I am calling the GET method in the constructor:

```
 constructor(
    ease: RoundProgressEase,
    private _router: Router,
    private formB: FormBuilder,
    private _authService: AuthService
  ) {
    for (let prop in ease) {
      if (prop.toLowerCase().indexOf("ease") > -1) {
        this.animations.push(prop);
      }
    }
    this._authService.getPoints().subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log("data points", res);
    });
  }
```

Also here is the endpoint at the backend:

```
    router.get(
      "/user/getCurrentPoints",
      isAuthenticated,
      userCtrl.getCurrentPoints
    );
```

Here is the middleware isAuthenticated:

```
  var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
      var token = req.headers["authorization"];
      console.log(req.header);
      token = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: null,
          msg: "You have to login first before you can access your lists.",
          data: null
        });
      }
      jwt.verify(token, req.app.get("secret"), function(err, decodedToken) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            error: err,
            msg: "Login timed out, please login again.",
            data: null
          });
        }
        req.decodedToken = decodedToken;
        console.log(req.decodedToken);
        next();
      });
    };
```

Finally, this is the `userCtrl.getCurrentPoints` controller method:

```
module.exports.getCurrentPoints = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("accessed get current points");
  if (!Validations.isString(req.decodedToken.user.username)) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      err: null,
      msg: "type parameter must be a valid String.",
      data: null
    });
  }
  User.find({ username: req.decodedToken.user.username }).exec(function(
    err,
    user
  ) {
    if (err) {

      return next(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      err: null,
      msg: "Current user points retrieved successfully.",
      data: user.points
    });
  });
};
```

This is the response i get

```
{err: null, msg: "Current user points retrieved successfully."}
```

The user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Voucher = mongoose.Schema.Types.Voucher;

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true

  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  region: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  building: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  },
  points: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
    min: 0
  },
  vouchers: {
    type: [Voucher],
    status:[String],
    required: false,
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: Date
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you get from backend? err or data?
First check that your request gets the backend api.
Second I saw that you checked for lower-case authorization in middle ware; maybe that's where things go wrong.
Third maybe the user has no points at all and by default the null field is eliminated from the response.

Comment: I get this message from the backend `{err: null, msg: "Current user points retrieved successfully."}` It is exactly like the 200 ok response but missing a data property. And it the user model does have a points field . I will add the schema to my question

Comment: I just add the schema

Comment: I think user object is null or there&#39;s something with that in the last part of the code

Comment: Just log the user object before responding back to ionic

Comment: I logged `req.decodedToken.user.username` and i got the following: `{ user: 
   { vouchers: [],
     _id: '5d3934b3821f916b6c904742',
     username: 'gigihadid',
     name: 'wwwwwwwwwww',
     region: 'wwwwwww',
     building: 2,
     password: 'marwamarwa',
     createdAt: '2019-07-25T04:48:51.755Z',
     __v: 0 },
  iat: 1564089577,
  exp: 1564132777 }`

Comment: I see no points field. Log user object and user.points before res.status